Does BKT transition exist in 2-dimensional non-interacting (ideal) Boson gas and why?
In 2D continuum system, the transition from the BKT phase to the normal phase seems to represent the superfluid is broken by the excitation of the single vortex. But why does superfluid exist in 2D continuum system at finite temperature?
